# Same route defined with different middleware called last wirted route issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, roles

Define the four routes with different middleware role wise.

Issue arrive is call DepartmentStaff Route every time.if i login Admin or Customer.

Call last written route every time.

```
//admin Route
Route::get('edit_profile', [UserController::class, 'edit_profile'])->name('edit_profile')->middleware(CheckAdminRole::class);
Route::post('profile_update', [UserController::class, 'profile_update'])->name('profile_update')->middleware(CheckAdminRole::class);
Route::get('change_password', [UserController::class, 'change_password'])->name('change_password')->middleware(CheckAdminRole::class);
Route::post('password_update', [UserController::class, 'password_update'])->name('password_update')->middleware(CheckAdminRole::class);

// Customer Route
Route::get('edit_profile', [UserController::class, 'edit_profile'])->name('edit_profile')->middleware(CheckCustomerRole::class);
Route::post('profile_update', [UserController::class, 'profile_update'])->name('profile_update')->middleware(CheckCustomerRole::class);
Route::get('change_password', [UserController::class, 'change_password'])->name('change_password')->middleware(CheckCustomerRole::class);
Route::post('password_update', [UserController::class, 'password_update'])->name('password_update')->middleware(CheckCustomerRole::class);

//DepartmentStaff Route
Route::get('edit_profile', [UserController::class, 'edit_profile'])->name('edit_profile')->middleware(CheckDepartmentStaffRole::class);
Route::post('profile_update', [UserController::class, 'profile_update'])->name('profile_update')->middleware(CheckDepartmentStaffRole::class);
Route::get('change_password', [UserController::class, 'change_password'])->name('change_password')->middleware(CheckDepartmentStaffRole::class);
Route::post('password_update', [UserController::class, 'password_update'])->name('password_update')->middleware(CheckDepartmentStaffRole::class);

//admin middleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->role == 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('error/404'); 
}
//customer middleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->role == 4) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('error/404');
}
//Department middleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->role == 2) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('error/404');
}
```

Comment: If you have more than 1 route with exact same name and key, of course it will override itself and will call last one. What are you trying to do actually? If user have one of these roles then he/she should have an access? Or he/she needs all these roles?

Comment: Use _one_ middleware that handles _all_ user roles

Comment: @brombeer how can posible one middleware?

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli I implement users' role wise different middleware with the same route.

Is it possible or any other way to do it?

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli One user can assign only one role.

Comment: @rakeshboliya Check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one middleware to check routes like:

```
//middleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (in_array(auth()->user()->role, [1, 2, 3])) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('error/404'); 
}
```

And routes:

```
Route::get('edit_profile', [UserController::class, 'edit_profile'])->name('edit_profile')->middleware(CheckRole::class);
Route::post('profile_update', [UserController::class, 'profile_update'])->name('profile_update')->middleware(CheckRole::class);
Route::get('change_password', [UserController::class, 'change_password'])->name('change_password')->middleware(CheckRole::class);
Route::post('password_update', [UserController::class, 'password_update'])->name('password_update')->middleware(CheckRole::class);
```